# Конвертировать в TKInter поле Entry в int

Tags: tkinter

Пытаюсь написать простой конвертор который принимает ввод Entry число и при нажатии на кнопку расчет делает расчет по формуле. Без get не переводит в int, но как только я привязываю get из окна программы пропадают все поля ввода. Есть у кого-то какие-то идеи как это победить?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Конвертор")
root.geometry("700x600")


class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


def new_window():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Листы в киллограммы")
    window.geometry("700x600")

    label0 = ttk.Label(window, text="Листы в кг.")
    label0.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

    label1 = ttk.Label(window, text="Ширина листа в мм. : ")
    label1.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

    entry_width = ttk.Entry(window)
    entry_width.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)
    width = entry_width.get()
    int_width = int(width)

    label2 = ttk.Label(window, text="Длинна листа в мм. : ")
    label2.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

    entry_height = ttk.Entry(window)
    entry_height.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)
    height = entry_height.get()
    int_height = int(height)

    label3 = ttk.Label(window, text="Масса листа в граммах : ")
    label3.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

    entry_mass = ttk.Entry(window)
    entry_mass.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)
    mass = entry_mass.get()
    int_mass = int(mass)

    label4 = ttk.Label(window, text="Количество листов в шт. : ")
    label4.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

    entry_sheets = ttk.Entry(window)
    entry_sheets.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)
    sheet = entry_sheets.get()
    int_sheets = int(sheet)

    label5 = ttk.Label(window, text="ИТОГО")
    label5.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

    def calc_1():
        answer = int_width * int_height * int_mass * int_sheets
        label5.config(text=answer)

    btn_calculated = ttk.Button(window, text="Рассчет", command=calc_1)
    btn_calculated.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)


btn_win1 = ttk.Button(text="Листы в киллограммы", command=new_window)
btn_win1.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
entry_width = ttk.Entry(window)
entry_width.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)
width = entry_width.get()
int_width = int(width)  # Ошибка здесь

entry_height = ttk.Entry(window)
entry_height.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)
height = entry_height.get()
int_height = int(height)  # И здесь

entry_mass = ttk.Entry(window)
entry_mass.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)
mass = entry_mass.get()
int_mass = int(mass)  # И здесь

entry_sheets = ttk.Entry(window)
entry_sheets.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)
sheet = entry_sheets.get()
int_sheets = int(sheet)  # И здесь
```

Вы пытаетесь преобразовать значения полей ввода в целые числа сразу после их создания. Но в этот момент поля ввода еще пусты, поэтому `entry_width.get()`, `entry_height.get()`, `entry_mass.get()` и `entry_sheets.get()` возвращают пустую строку, которую нельзя преобразовать в целое число. Это вызывает ошибку. Преобразование в целые числа должно происходить после того, как пользователь введет данные и нажмет кнопку “Рассчет”.

Вот исправленный код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Конвертор")
root.geometry("700x600")


class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


def new_window():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Листы в киллограммы")
    window.geometry("700x600")

    label0 = ttk.Label(window, text="Листы в кг.")
    label0.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

    label1 = ttk.Label(window, text="Ширина листа в мм. : ")
    label1.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

    entry_width = ttk.Entry(window)
    entry_width.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

    label2 = ttk.Label(window, text="Длинна листа в мм. : ")
    label2.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

    entry_height = ttk.Entry(window)
    entry_height.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

    label3 = ttk.Label(window, text="Масса листа в граммах : ")
    label3.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

    entry_mass = ttk.Entry(window)
    entry_mass.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

    label4 = ttk.Label(window, text="Количество листов в шт. : ")
    label4.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

    entry_sheets = ttk.Entry(window)
    entry_sheets.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

    label5 = ttk.Label(window, text="ИТОГО")
    label5.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

    def calc_1():
        width = entry_width.get()
        height = entry_height.get()
        mass = entry_mass.get()
        sheet = entry_sheets.get()

        if width and height and mass and sheet:
            int_width = int(width)
            int_height = int(height)
            int_mass = int(mass)
            int_sheets = int(sheet)

            answer = int_width * int_height * int_mass * int_sheets
            label5.config(text=answer)
        else:
            label5.config(text="Пожалуйста, заполните все поля.")

    btn_calculated = ttk.Button(window, text="Рассчет", command=calc_1)
    btn_calculated.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)


btn_win1 = ttk.Button(text="Листы в киллограммы", command=new_window)
btn_win1.pack(anchor="center", padx=20, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.